# If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are injections, then there's a bijection $h:A\to B$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Is this proof valid? I'm pretty sure the idea is correct but not sure if ive written it correctly.

**Theorem.** If $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ are injections, then there's a bijection $h:A\rightarrow B$.
**Proof.**
So we have injections $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$. Assume that $B\setminus \text{ran}(f)$ is not empty, i.e. $f$ is not surjective. For any $\displaystyle b\notin ran( f)$, let its *sequence* of distinct $\displaystyle a$'s be defined by:

$$a_{1} =g(b)$$
$$a_{n+1} =g( f( a_{n}))$$

To see why they are distinct, consider $\displaystyle a_{i}$ and $\displaystyle a_{j}$ for $\displaystyle i< j$. Then since $\displaystyle f$ and $\displaystyle g$ are injective, the equality $\displaystyle a_{i} =a_{j}$ can be reduced to $\displaystyle b=g( f( a_{j-i}))$, which is not possible since $\displaystyle b\notin ran( f)$. As an example, consider $\displaystyle a_{3} =g( f( g( f( g( f( b))))))$ and $\displaystyle a_{5} =g( f( g( f( g( f( g( f( g( f( b))))))))))$.
Then $\displaystyle a_{3} =a_{5}$ is same as saying $\displaystyle b=g( f( g( f( b))))$.

Each $a \in A$ is either in exactly one sequence or in none of them. Define $h:A\rightarrow B$ by

$$
h(a) = 
\begin{cases} 
g^{-1}(a) & \text{if $a$ in some sequence} \\
f(a) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

To prove that $h$ is injective, we prove that we can't have $h(a_1) = h(a_2)$ with $h(a_1) = g^{-1}(a_1)$ and $h(a_2) = f(a_2)$. Let $g^{-1}(a_1) = b_1$. Now $a_1$ is an element of a sequence, so either $b_1 \notin \text{ran}(f)$ or $b_1 \in \text{ran}(f)$.

- **Case 1.** $b_1 \notin \text{ran}(f)$

  - Then $b_1$ i.e. $g^{-1}(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$.
- **Case 2.** $b_1 \in \text{ran}(f)$

  - Then $f^{-1}(b_1) = a'_{1}$. Now $a'_{1} \neq a_{2}$, since $a'_{1}$ is in a sequence but $a_{2}$ is not. That implies $f(a'_{1}) \neq f(a_{2})$, which means $b_1$ i.e. $g^{-1}(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$.

To see that $h$ is surjective, take $b \in B$ and let $a = g(b)$. If $a$ is in a sequence, then $h(a) = g^{-1}(a) = b$. Otherwise $a$ is not in a sequence, so it must be that $b \in \text{ran}(f)$. Then $f^{-1}(b) = a'$ is not in a sequence either, so $h(a') = f(a') = b$.

Comment: I agree that $g(b)$ and $ g(f(g(b)))$ are distinct, but since $b'$ is in fact in the range of f, you can't necessarily assume that all elements: $g(b)$, $g(f(g(b)))$, $g(f(g(f(g(b))))$, and so on are distinct, right?

Comment: @Aria i've edited it now, is it valid?

Comment: This is basically the same as the proof of [Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) by chasing preimages.

Comment: @curiousCprogrammer1231, Looks correct to me.